# Functions that refer to blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am currently using W8 and Excel 2010. I am trying to write what I thought was a straightforward `"IF"` function for each cell in a column; whereby if a specific cell in the same row is blank, I want the cell containing the formula also to display blank. If not then I want a default text to appear.  Here is my formula entered in `F2`:

```
=If(A2="";"";"default text").
```

Column A contains a name and if it contains any text, then the default text is intended to be a hyperlinked address to the person's photograph on the same disk drive.

The problem is the formula won't work and it highlights `""` as being the error when trying to express blank.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula just needs commas instead of semi colons.  The working version should be as follows:  =If(A2="","","default text")

Comment: The semicolons are likely just a difference in regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

To cope with the possibility that A2 could either be a blank string, or an empty cell, I would recode the function as follows:

```
=If(len(A2)=0;"";"default text")
```

I'm assuming your use of semi-colons is due to your locale. If not, you need to substitute them with commas.

Answer (score 0):

For those instances as you described, I use an [`IS`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/is-functions-HP005209147.aspx) function to determine if the cell is empty; specifically `ISBLANK`.

> Each of these functions, referred to collectively as the IS functions,
>   checks the type of value and returns TRUE or FALSE depending on the
>   outcome. For example, the ISBLANK function returns the logical value
>   TRUE if value is a reference to an empty cell; otherwise it returns
>   FALSE.

Therefore, you can nest the `ISBLANK` in you `IF` statement as follows.

`=If(ISBLANK(A2);"";"default text")`

If it finds `A2` to be blank, it will leave it blank, otherwise it will display the default text.